# Create a credit card payment process using CyberSource

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create a credit card payment process but I can not accept card details on application screen because of PCI compliance issue.
My application uses CyberSource as payment processor. We are using simple order API. In the current process of my application user has to create a Credit Card profile first. We create profile using CyberSource secure acceptance. and then we charge some amount on that profile using OnDemand payment.

Is there a way to charge credit card by accepting the card details on CyberSource screen? How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be available in cybersource's documentation guide - may be an API or some jar file through which you can charge card via cybersource

Comment: I tried searching through the documentation, but could not find any solution.

Comment: Then you need to contact their support team

Comment: I'll try to connect to them.

Comment: Have you tried obtaining an SubscriptionId for CC details from CyberSource and using that subscription id for transactions